# Jquery Class selector on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i am using select class on click though its working fine but its a long process for me can anyone tell me simple and short process for it my code is given below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() { 
           $("#menu-item1").click(function() {
              $('#menu-item1').addClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item2').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item3').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item4').removeClass('li_select');
        });

           $("#menu-item2").click(function() {
              $('#menu-item1').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item2').addClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item3').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item4').removeClass('li_select');
        });

           $("#menu-item3").click(function() {
              $('#menu-item1').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item2').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item3').addClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item4').removeClass('li_select');
        });


           $("#menu-item4").click(function() {
              $('#menu-item1').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item2').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item3').removeClass('li_select');
              $('#menu-item4').addClass('li_select');
        });

      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the link http://jsfiddle.net/G49SQ/ ..

HTML :

```
<ul id="menu-item">
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
$(document).on("click","#menu-item li",function(){
    $("#menu-item").find("li").removeClass('li_select');
    $(this).addClass('li_select');
});
```

Comment: thanks its working fine but i want when the page get loaded first one should be selected and when i click on other it become select and first select removed

Comment: hi add the li_select class while loading the page. No need to do this js. do it in html

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $menu = $("[id^='menu-item'");
    $menu.click(function () {
        $menu.removeClass('li_select');
        $(this).addClass('li_select');
    });
});
```

Comment: Good solution, but shouldn't it be `$("[id^=...`? (Or, better, have the OP give a common class to each menu item and just select by that class.)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to palash's answer could be something like this ( a bit more specific I guess ) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //define all your elements
    var items = $('#menu-item1,#menu-item2,#menu-item3,#menu-item4');
    //remove the class onclick from all items, 
    //and then apply it to the element that was clicked.
    items.click(function() {
        items.removeClass('li_select');
        $(this).addClass('li_select');
    });
});
```

Comment: _"easier to understand imo"_ - Obviously a matter of opinion like you said (pre edit), but I actually find the other solution easier to understand because the selector is short and thus clear that it is selecting a bunch of very similar ids. If you list all of the ids out in full it forces the reader to check the whole list to make sure they're similar, and also if the html is updated to add another menu item that requires a change to the JS.

Comment: @nnnnnn I totally agree, hence why i changed the description of the alternative to be around specificity- It seems the poster is a beginner and in the conscience of providing a more *tangible* block of code ( referencing the id's in the original source ) I thought it may be worth it.

Comment: @nnnnnn furthermore, there's always a chance that there are items with id's that follow similar syntax that may be caught in the other answer and the poster would most likely not know how to remedy that ( since there's no /obviously readable to a beginner/ representation of which selectors are being caught